# how validate this regexp with ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I need to apply a validation in the card number. so I want the input below to show true if it is valid and false if it complies with any of the numbers of the exclusion pattern.
I'm trying but always throws me false

the api of mercadopago returns the following exclusion pattern and with this format

```
"^(400276|400615|402914|404625)"
```

**controller**

```
$scope.patron='^(400276|400615|402914|404625)';
```

**html**

```
  <input type="number"
           id="numeroTarjeta"
           name="numeroTarjeta"
           required
           ng-pattern='patron'                                 
           ng-model="$parent.numeroTarjeta"/>

    input valid? = {{formulario.numeroTarjeta.$valid}}
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would disagree.  https://plnkr.co/edit/9uaNSZt6GpQtkpmOaWur?p=preview

Comment: @Ivan Paredes, model parameter looks different from the variable you are checking..

Comment: @SunilBN it works!!! thank you very much!